# Problems with jquery mobile and DateBox

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a problem with my datepicker. I use http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/ for the picker.

As you see in my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/SrHNe/
It does not change page, even thoug it is trigging the alert

```
$('#datepicker').on('change', function(e,p) {

    var date = $(this).val();
    var location = "index.php?date=" + date;
    alert(location);
    window.location.href(location);
});
```

I have tried with window.location.assign(location) also, but here it will only work on the today button "gå til i dag" in the buttom of the daypicker. ? how can that be? I can not use mobile.changePage( to [, options ] ) because I need the changing without ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.location.href` is a property, not a method. You have to assign to it instead of calling it:

```
window.location.href = location;
```

**EDIT:** The second problem seems to come from the way jQuery Mobile dismisses the date box popup. It looks like it involves changing pages, so assigning to `location.href` will not work properly unless you delay it slightly with `setTimeout()`:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = location;
}, 10);
```

You will find an updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SrHNe/2/).

Comment: now it change if I am using the today button "gå til i dag" in the buttom of the daypicker, but will still not change if I am clicking on a date.

Comment: Thank you very much! Working perfect now! :D